# Downloading email messages as text files (multiple accounts) from command line

Tags: command-line, email

I would like to use some tool from command line, to check and download mail, from different providers (gmail, hotmail, yahoo...) periodically and automatically, and save them as text files, preferably a text file for each email. I don't want my previous emails, so it shoud be possible to specify not to download previous emails, but only new ones since this solution is set up. I have been looking for such a thing and found fetchmail, but it saves all the messages in a single mbox file. What do you suggest? Thanks

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the question suggested, since I am not going to send any email from this computer. It will not even have a keyboard or mouse connected. My question is about downloading all my emails individually as plain text file ("readable"), and stored in txt format.

Comment: I have a method for saving emails to text files with `mutt` command line tool, but I only know of one-by-one approach

Answer (score 0):

You can either chop the mbox file into pieces using a script ([example](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/splitmbox.py.html)), or use `fetchmail` and save the messages directly to a [maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) folder.

Depending on what you're going to do with the messages you may be better off using a homemade solution altogether.

Comment: OP asks for a solution to save each message in a separate file. It's possible with fetchmail, but you should give more details in your answer.

Comment: Thanks both for your interest. @Jan I would appreciate if you could elaborate a bit more, specially on the second option (fetchmail+maildir). About the script option, how does it work exactly, I have to run it after new mails have arrived, when they get stored in the mbox? As new mails come, they will be in same mbox, but if I run the script again, won't it extract once and again all the previous messages (that were already extracted the first time I ran the script? Cause I don't want that, plus it would be useless extra work. Regards.